# ExtJS Web Sockets: Ext.ux.WebSocket eventName error

Tags: extjs, websocket, netty

I'm using the `Ext.ux.data.proxy.WebSocket` extension, and have the following store definition:

```
Ext.define('ExtMVC.store.StatsWebSocket', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'store.statswebsocket',
    requires: [
        'Ext.ux.data.proxy.WebSocket'
    ],


    model: 'ExtMVC.model.Stock',

    proxy: {
        type: 'websocket',
        storeId: 'StatsWebSocket',
        url: 'ws://localhost:8087/ws',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'cis4-file-stats'
        }
    }
});
```

Using Chrome debugger, I can see that the data is actually retrieved but somehow it doesn't end up in my Grid. The point where the store is used in the grid is shown below:

```
initComponent: function(){


        var store = Ext.create('ExtMVC.store.StatsWebSocket');

        Ext.apply(this, {
            height: this.height,
            store: store,
           ....
```

I've followed the instructions at [URL]https://market.sencha.com/extensions/ext-ux-data-proxy-websocket[/URL], but nothing seems to work. Any idea what I may be doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Every time the browser receives data from the socket server, the error:

```
Uncaught Ext.ux.WebSocket.receiveEventMessage(): (No description provided)
```

is thrown.

The error occurs in this function of the Ext.ux.WebSocket extension:

```
fireEventArgs: function(eventName, args) {
  eventName = eventName.toLowerCase();   // ERROR occurs here
  var me = this,
  events = me.events,
  event = events && events[eventName],
  ret = true;
  if (event && me.hasListeners[eventName]) {
     ret = me.continueFireEvent(eventName, args || emptyArray, event.bubble);
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Environment: ExtJS 4.1, Netty  3.5.0.Final.

FYI: I've also posted this question [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?262589-Ext.ux.data.proxy.WebSocket-receiveEventMessage%28%29-%28No-description-provided%29&p=962308).

**UPDATE:**
My question has been answered on the [Sencha Forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?261699-Ext.ux.data.proxy.WebSocket-is-among-us!/page2) by the developer of the extension, Wilky. In a nutshell, the JSON retured by the socket server must conform to a specific structure. It must have 'event' and 'data' nodes:

```
{"event": "read", "data": [{....}, {....}]}
```

"event" can be any of the CRUD methods; read, update, destroy or create. "data" corresponds to your application-specific data. All I needed to do was alter the structure of my JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it has anything to do with your problem but I don't think the storeId definition inside
the proxy would work. Generally it should be defined as a config option of the store, but in your case you use it inside a proxy, which is defined in the store, so you don't need it at all.

Comment: thanks. But changing this doesn't bring about any changes. I followed the guide at http://wilk.github.io/Ext.ux.data.proxy.WebSocket/. It uses the same approach. The actual error is thrown at the `receiveEventMessage()` function of the WebSocket (see https://github.com/wilk/ExtJS-WebSocket) upon which this proxy is based.